# How to stop the label:before from wrapping when the label wraps?

Tags: html, css

### What it consists of

`label:before` is a custom checkbox and `label:after` is the check mark in the custom checkbox. The original input[type=checkbox]`is set to`display: hidden`.

I have a list and every `li` in that list has two icons, then the `label:before` and after that, there are two icons absolutely positioned to right.

### The Problem

When the `label`'s text takes up more than one line, then the `label:before` element wraps with it.

I couldn't get the jsFiddle working. So, I'm uploading a picture of the problem and the code.

### What it is supposed to do

I do not want the `label:before` or `input[type=checkbox]` to wrap when the label's content or text wraps.

First image shows how the wrapping moves the checkbox with it. This is wrong.

Second image shows how it supposed to be wrapping. This is correct.

### How it's currently working and doing other stuff

Wrapping of the label's content is done by `word-break: break-all` because label's width is not known.

All of the icons are in `display: inline-block`.

The `label` is set to `position: relative` and the custom checkbox is set to `position: absolute`. So, that the checkbox stays at the side of the label.

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px; 
  }

li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  line-height: 16px; 
}

li .dropdown,  li .cross,  li .drag,  li .setIcon {
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 18px; } //All the icons

     li .drag {
      margin-right: 5px; //The three lines icon
      margin-left: 5px; 
     }
     li .cross,  li .setIcon {
      position: absolute; } //Delete Icon and the settings icon 

     li .cross {
      right: 0px; } //Delete Icon

     li .setIcon {
      right: 23px; } //Settings Icon

   input[type="checkbox"]:checked,  input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
    display: none; }

     input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,  input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
      word-break: break-all;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-right: 45px;
      vertical-align: middle; }

     input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,  input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      line-height: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #E7E3E3;
      border-radius: 2px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

     input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after,  input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
      content: '✔';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 4px;
      line-height: 0.8;
      color: #42A5F5; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><i class="dropdown material-icons md-dark">expand_more</i><i class="drag material-icons md-dark">reorder</i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="0">
        <label for="0">Single Line Content</label><i class="material-icons md-dark setIcon">settings</i><i class="material-icons md-dark cross">delete_forever</i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="dropdown material-icons md-dark">expand_more</i><i class="drag material-icons md-dark">reorder</i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2">
        <label for="2">Multi Line Content Multi Line Content Multi Line Content Multi Line ContentMulti Line Content Multi Line Content</label><i class="material-icons md-dark setIcon">settings</i><i class="material-icons md-dark cross">delete_forever</i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="dropdown material-icons md-dark">expand_more</i><i class="drag material-icons md-dark">reorder</i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3">
        <label for="3">Single Line Content</label><i class="material-icons md-dark setIcon">settings</i><i class="material-icons md-dark cross">delete_forever</i>
    </li>
    <li><i class="dropdown material-icons md-dark">expand_more</i><i class="drag material-icons md-dark">reorder</i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4">
        <label for="4">Very Long Multi Line Content - fgkfbhjdfbbhjbfhjdfbjhdfbjdfhbdhjbdjhfbdjhdfbjhfbhjdbhjbdfhjbdfjhbdfhjbdfjhdfkfdhjgfbhjbhjbdjhbgjhfbhjdfb</label><i class="material-icons md-dark setIcon">settings</i><i class="material-icons md-dark cross">delete_forever</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**How it currently is**

[image: The Picture with the problem]

**How I want it to appear**

[image]

Comment: @OopsD'oh - I've edited the post with another image showing how I want the the content to be displayed. The CSS code above is only for this current thing, it only shows the rules for list and the icons.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Add padding left and right to the `<li>` elements in the width of the icons. Then change the position of all icons to absolute and apply the top/left position values...

So the icons are all "outside" of the label, but in the padding area of the `<li>`.

Your icons are 14px in width and have a margin of 5 so they are 24 pixel wide completely. On the left side you have 3 icons so padding-left would be 72 pixel. On the right side (2 icons) padding would be 48 pixel.

```
/* ... keep your current code and add or change following: */

li {
  /* ... */
  padding: 0 48px 0 72px;
}

/* no need to change padding of the label as it should
   take full with of the <li> container */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
  word-break: break-all;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

/* All icons with position absolute */
li .dropdown, li .cross, li .drag, li .setIcon {
  position absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Then add position values. Your <li> has position relative,
   so the values are orientated on the li container... */
li .dropdown {
  left: 0;
}
li .drag {
  left: 24px;
}
li .cross {
  right: 0px;
}
li .setIcon {
  right: 24px;
}

/* Third icon left side: Checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  position: absolute; /* is already set, keep it*/
  left: 48px;
  top: 0px;
}

/* And modify the left/top position of the ✔ so that it fits again */
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work for this case because I have a sub list in that list and it gets weird when I apply the above rules. So, instead of applying absolute padding, I'm giving the label a width and then aligning the icons with vertical-align: top. It works perfectly. :)

Comment: @Lavios Great. If your solution in working I'd suggest to selt-answer you question so others with a similar problem know how to solve it. You can also accept your own answer as solution after a couple of hours so it's clear that the problem is solved...